# SQL Query help Join

Tags: sql, join

I have a table called team

I need to select a coach who also might be a player on the team....

The attributes for the table are
(teamID, playerID, role)

I'm able to select all coaches or all players but not sure how to select one which is both.....

```
select *
from isPlaying h
where h.role= 'Coach';
```

Thanks

Comment: what does "might" mean in this situation?Is there any table for only players or just coaches?Just Team?

Comment: team ID = team1
player ID = p1
role = player 


team ID = team1
player ID = p1
role = coach

This should give me this playerID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select playerID
from isPlaying coach join isPlaying player on
   coach.playerID = player.playerID
where
   coach.role = 'Coach' and
   player.role = 'Player'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from isplaying 
where playerid in (
                   Select playerid 
                   from playerid 
                   where role="coach"
                   );
```

This is a nested query.

Comment: the requirement is "also" so that would require an "OR" in the where clause. Your suggestion only selects players who "ARE" coaches.

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty way to do this would be:

```
select *
from isPlaying h
where h.role = 'Player'
and h.playerID in 
 (select playerID from isPlaying where h.role = 'Coach')
```

This is assuming that a coach could not play for a different team than he coaches for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT playerID
  FROM isPlaying 
 WHERE role = 'Coach'
INTERSECT
SELECT playerID
  FROM isPlaying 
 WHERE role = 'Player';
```